# Linux command outputs in splunk

Tags: linux, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I'm struggling to understand how I would get the output of a linux command such as vmstat or iostat into splunk where i can use the output to create a time graph.

Can someone point me in the right direction at all?

Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a match for [scripted inputs](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/Data/Setupcustominputs)!